# TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: <function <lambda> at 0x7f1f357c6160> of type <class 'function'>

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I'm using the following snippet which creates a list of all `.csv` files in a directory in Databricks.

```
csv_dir = '/my_dir/'
csv_paths = list(filter(lambda x: '.csv' in x, os.listdir(csv_dir)))
```

However it yields the following error

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: <function <lambda> at 0x7f1f357c6160> of type <class 'function'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

I'm guessing my pure Python code has been mistaken for PySpark code. I tried using `%python` at the top of the cell and it still yielded the same result.

Yes, I have used PySpark and Python interchangeably in the notebook but I've never faced this issue when using `lambda` functions.

Is there a workaround to escape this behavior?

*Please Advise*

Comment: did you import pyspark's functions using `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`?

Comment: Yup! I did use `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely as you guessed that your code uses [Pyspark's filter](http://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.filter.html) function instead of Python's built-in [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter). The best practice to import Pyspark functions is to use an alias, e.g `import pyspark.sql.functions as F` so that those functions will not be conflicted with the built-ins with the same names.

But, if you already imported `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`, you can call the built-in `filter` explicitly using `__builtin__.filter`

```
csv_paths = list(__builtin__.filter(lambda x: '.csv' in x, os.listdir(csv_dir)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Works Great! But why does the error point to `lambda` instead instead of `filter`

Comment: the error is referring the type of argument you provided to `filter`, pyspark's filter needs an argument of a string or column object, but you provided a lambda function (since you thought it is the builtin `filter`).